# Syntax for linking fragments to other activity

Tags: android, button, fragment, swipeview

What is the syntax for a button in a fragment that when is clicked it would go to a listview activity?

Any response would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Is the fragment housed inside the ListActivity? Please post any code you have of the ListActivity and fragment.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/jhf1TntZ
This is my coding for the fragment where I want the button.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/VjK3FRib
This is where it should direct after click.

The first code is a swipeview activity.

Answer (score 1):

In the code your provided in the comments above:

```
    public class Exerfrag extends Fragment{
    private Button button1;
    Context context;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.exer,     container, false);

    button1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(context, Listview.class);
            startActivity(intent);
    }
    });
return view;
}
}
```

`context` is never initialised. Use `getActivity()` instead so that your `onClick` method looks like this:

```
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(), Listview.class);
            startActivity(intent);
    }
    });
```

**Edit**:

Your second `Activity` also appears problematic:

```
public class Listview extends Activity {
        ExpandableListView exv;

        public Listview() {
                // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
                exv=(ExpandableListView)findViewById(R.id.expandableListView1);
                exv.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this));
        }

}
```

You never call `onCreate()`, inside which you should place the rest of your set-up code, including`setContentView(R.layout.-)` to establish your layout.

**Edit 2:**

```
public class Listview extends Activity {
        ExpandableListView exv;

        protected void onCreate(android.os.Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.listview);

        };


        public Listview() {
                // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
                exv=(ExpandableListView)findViewById(R.id.expandableListView1);
                exv.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this));
        }
```

The following lines:

```
exv=(ExpandableListView)findViewById(R.id.expandableListView1);
                exv.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this));
```

Need to be placed inside `onCreate()`. The section that reads like this:

```
public Listview(){
    ....
}
```

is called a `constructor`. It is actually not required at all in this case, so my advice would be to delete it entirely so that your entire class looks like this:

```
public class Listview extends Activity {
            ExpandableListView exv;

            protected void onCreate(android.os.Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.listview);
                    exv=(ExpandableListView)findViewById(R.id.expandableListView1);
                    exv.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this));
               }
```

This is fairly basic stuff when it comes to Android, so I would perhaps suggest taking a look at the [developer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)) docs for a sample `Activity` class, and a site like [Vogella](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/android.html)

Comment: @Mae Your second Activity never calls `onCreate()`. Take a look at my edit.

Comment: Im sorry, Im still learning how to do things. Do you mind checking what Ive done?

http://pastebin.com/F6YvQ2pf